# How to change Data Point Limit of Power BI Custom Visual

Tags: powerbi

I created a Custom visual for Power BI. It is working properly but I noticed that the data points allowed to render is limited to 1000. According to the it can be configured up to 30,000.

How to increase the data point limit on power bi custom visual?

Thank you.

Marius

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [dataReductionAlgorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/dataview-mappings#data-reduction-algorithm) property in the `capabilities.json` file. For example:

```
"dataReductionAlgorithm": {
    "window": {
        "count": 30000
    }
}
```

Note that if you use `window` as I did in the code (instead of `top`, `bottom`, or `sample`), you will be also able to use the [Fetch more data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/fetch-more-data) feature to bypass the 30K rows limit.